# android listview item value

Tags: android, listview

I want to know how to get the listview item value like this

```
item1
item2
```

I want to get first item value item1, like this code

```
if (listview part of value == item1)
{
// do something
}
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: elaborate your question. and show what you have tried.It must be shown how your listview structure and which item in the listview you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very sparse on details so I'll take my best guess at interpreting it (consider expanding your question).

You want to get an item from the listadapter at a given position, yes? If so...

```
yourListView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

See also:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#getAdapter()
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to guess your question.
You want, maybe, that when user clicks on an item execute some code.
If this is your case then you can do in this way:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentAdapter, View view, int position,
                         long id) {
  // do your code here
  }
 }
```

where lv is your Listview. If you want to have more information go to my blog [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/09/listviewpart-1.html)